# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \left( i \right) \cdot \left( \frac {e ^ \frac{i}{n}}{n ^ 2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \left( i \right) \cdot \left( \frac {e ^ \frac{i}{n}}{n ^ 2}\right)$$

The sum is an AGP, and can readily be solved if one has the AGP formula at hand. Refer :

[https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-geometric-progression/#:~:text=Now%20let%27s%20derive%20a%20general%20formula%20for%20the,in%20the%20above%20example%20to%20prove%20this%20theorem%3A](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-geometric-progression/#:%7E:text=Now%20let%27s%20derive%20a%20general%20formula%20for%20the,in%20the%20above%20example%20to%20prove%20this%20theorem%3A)

What other way is there to evaluate this sum?

Comment: This is the Riemann sum for $$\int_0^1 xe^x\,dx,$$ with an extra term, but the first term is zero so can be ignored.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am not familiar with a Riemann sum. Is it when a summation can be changed into an integral, when n tends to infinity, 1/n can be changed to dx and i/n can be replaced by f(x)? The question presumes only a highschool background.

Comment: Well, limits are part of calculus, and the most direct way to solve this limit is to see its limit is the integral, again calculus. Essentially, the sum is an estimate of the area of the curve using rectangles, and as $n\to\infty,$ the limit is the area.

Comment: Thank you. I looked up the Riemann sum, and realized I am familiar with the concept. Just wasn't sure about the naming. The division of area under a curve into rectangles is perhaps the first thing that high school introduces to students.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\geq 2$ and $t\in (-n,n)$, let :
$$f_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n} e^{kt/n} = \frac{1-e^{(n+1)t/n}}{n(1-e^{t/n})}$$
These functions are smooth and we can compute their first derivative, in two different ways. On one hand :
\begin{align}
f_n'(t) &= \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{n^2}e^{kt/n}
\end{align}

and on the other hand :
\begin{align}
f_n'(t)& = \frac{-\frac{n+1}{n}e^{(n+1)t/n}(1-e^{t/n})+\frac 1n e^{t/n}(1-e^{(n+1)t/n})}{n(1-e^{t/n})^2} 
\end{align}

The sum we wanted to compute was :
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k}{n^2}e^{k/n} = f'_n(1) =\frac{-\frac{n+1}{n}e^{(n+1)/n}(1-e^{1/n})+\frac 1n e^{1/n}(1-e^{(n+1)/n})}{n(1-e^{1/n})^2} $$

Comment: Thank you. In a way, what you have computed is the sum of an AGP. Thanks for the calculation. It was hinted at in another problem, but this completes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using series expansions for large $n$
$$i\frac{ e^{i/n}}{n^2}=\frac{i}{n^2}+\frac{i^2}{n^3}+\frac{i^3}{2 n^4}+\frac{i^4}{6
   n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ Summing up to $n$
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^ni\frac{ e^{i/n}}{n^2}=\frac{n+1}{2 n}+\frac{(n+1) (2 n+1)}{6 n^2}+\frac{(n+1)^2}{8 n^2}+\frac{(n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right)}{180 n^4}+\cdots$$
$$S_n=\frac{(n+1) \left(357 n^3+123 n^2+2 n-2\right)}{360 n^4}+\cdots$$
$$S_n=\frac{119}{120}+\frac{4}{3 n}+\frac{25}{72 n^2}-\frac{1}{180
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ Add the next term to get
$$S_n=\frac{719}{720}+\frac{65}{48 n}+\frac{35}{96 n^2}-\frac{13}{1440
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Now, I am  ready to bet about the limit (joke).

**Edit**

Making it mode formal, considering the first expansion to $k$ terms
$$i\frac{ e^{i/n}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=2}^k \frac{i^{k-1} n^{-k}}{(k-2)!}+ O\left(\frac{1}{n^{k+1}}\right)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i^{k-1} n^{-k}}{(k-2)!}=\frac{n^{-k} H_n^{(1-k)}}{(k-2)!}=\frac{n^{-k}}{(k-2)!}\Big[n^k \left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{k-1}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)+\zeta (1-k) \Big]$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{n^{-k}}{(k-2)!}\Big[n^k \left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{k-1}{12
   n^2}\right) \Big]=1+\frac{e}{2 n}+\frac{e}{6 n^2}$$

Comment: So, the answer is 1?

Comment: @thewinster. Start the bets ! Yes, it is. Cheers :-)

Comment: That first statement isn't true, because $i=n$ is possible. You can only get $O(i^5/n^6)$ in general.